# Find the $y$-coordinate of the point $B$ with $x$-coordinate $2$ on the line through points $A(-7, -10)$ and $C(10,-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider points $A=(−7,−10)$ and $C = (10, -1)$.  The point $B$ is on the line passing through $A$ and $C$. The $x$-coordinate of $B$ is $2$.   Determine the $y$-coordinate of point $B$.

I've been trying to figure out the answer using $y=mx+b$.  One answer I saw for this problem calculates the $y$-intercept at $-107$ and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get there.  Can anyone help me out?  Thanks!

Comment: The slope of the line is $9/17$ (using $A$ and $C$). The slope is also $(-10-y)/(-7-2)$ (using $A$ and $B$), where $y$ is the $y$-coordinate of $B$. Equate these two expressions and solve for $y$.

Answer (score 2):

The line through the two points has slope
$$
m = \frac{-1 + 10}{10 +7} = \frac{9}{17}.
$$
Now find the $y$-intercept $b$ so that you get an equation for the line $y = \frac{9}{17}x + b$. You know the $x$-coordinate to $B$ is $2$ so to find the $y$-coordinate just use the equation you just found: $y = \frac{9}{17}\cdot 2 + b$.

Comment: @user46944: Yeah, I just realized that,

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the point-slope form of the equation of a line.

If you have a point $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ on a line, and you know the slope $m$, the equation of the line is then $$y - y_{1} = m(x - x_{1}) $$

So, your point could be $(-7,-10)$ or $(10,-1)$ (no matter which one you choose, you will get the same answer).

So, let's choose the first one.  The slope $m$ is $\dfrac{-1 - (-10)}{10 - (-7)} = \dfrac{9}{17}$, so the equation of the line is:

$y - (-10) = \dfrac{9}{17}(x - (-7))$

So $y = \dfrac{9}{17}x + \dfrac{9}{17}(7) - 10$

So $y = \dfrac{9}{17}x + \dfrac{63}{17} - \dfrac{170}{17}$

So $y = \dfrac{9}{17}x - \dfrac{107}{17}$

Now, if you plug in the $x$-coordinate $x = 2$ into the above formula, and add the numbers, you should get the $y$-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, the equation of the line $AC$ passing through the points $A(-7, -10)$ & $C(10, -1)$ is given as $$y-(-10)=\frac{-10-(-1)}{-7-10}(x-(-7))$$ $$9x-17y=107$$ now, setting $x=2$ in the above, equation $$9(2)-17y=107$$$$\implies \color{red}{y=-\frac{89}{17}}$$